# Want to show image caotion or title above portfolio image

Tags: wordpress, popup, title, portfolio

For a recently developed wordpress website http://stc.co.in, I'm using Huge-IT portfolio to show the projects in each sectors. On clicking on projects a popup is showing with multiple images. Now I want to show image caption or title above the big image which was added while uploading image through WordPress. Please guide how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin cant let you do it simply with text editor, in wordpress you need to search the specific section you want and work on php file.

When you have founded it you can put an html section with your title.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I traced the php file section, but how to fetch the image title and add to it?
<?php  if($row->image_url != ';'){ ?>
     <img title=""  alt="<?php echo $row->name; ?>" id="wd-cl-img<?php echo $key; ?>" src="<?php echo $imgurl[0]; ?>" />
                    
     <?php } else { ?>
     <img alt="<?php echo $row->name; ?>" id="wd-cl-img<?php echo $key; ?>" src="images/noimage.jpg" />
     <?php
     } ?>

Comment: @vrajesh answered you with a great big image...follow his advice. hope you resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

you need to made changes in plugin file..

**follow path** :

> wordpress-sitename/wp-content/plugins/portfolio-gallery/Front_end/portfolio_front_end_view.php

[image]

**modify line :**

```
   <ul id="huge_it_portfolio_popup_list_<?php echo $portfolioID; ?>">
    <?php
    foreach($images as $key=>$row)
    {


        $imgurl=explode(";",$row->image_url);
        array_pop($imgurl);
        $link = $row->sl_url;
        $descnohtml=strip_tags($row->description);
        $result = substr($descnohtml, 0, 50);

        ?>
        <li class="pupup-element" id="huge_it_portfolio_pupup_element_<?php echo $row->id; ?>">

            <div class="heading-navigation_<?php echo $portfolioID; ?>">
                <a href="#close" class="close"></a>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="popup-wrapper_<?php echo $portfolioID; ?>">
                <div class="image-block_<?php echo $portfolioID; ?>">
                <?php   if($paramssld["ht_view2_show_popup_title"]=='on'){?><h3 class="title"><?php echo $row->name; ?></h3><?php } ?>
                    <?php   if($row->image_url != ';'){ ?>
                    <img alt="<?php echo $row->name; ?>" id="wd-cl-img<?php echo $key; ?>" src="<?php echo $imgurl[0]; ?>" />
                    <?php       
                                        global $wpdb;
                                    $cimg_url = $imgurl[0];                             
                                    $attachment = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE guid='".$cimg_url."'",'ARRAY_A');                               
                                    $attachment_title = get_the_title($attachment[0]['ID']);

                    ?>
                    <div class="cls_img_ttl" id="main_img_ttl"><?php echo $attachment_title; ?></div>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <img alt="<?php echo $row->name; ?>" id="wd-cl-img<?php echo $key; ?>" src="images/noimage.jpg" />
                    <?php
                    } ?>                    
                </div>
                <div class="right-block">
                    <?php if($paramssld["ht_view2_show_popup_title"]=='on'){?><h3 class="title"><?php echo $row->name; ?></h3><?php } ?>

                    <?php if($paramssld["ht_view2_thumbs_position"]=='before' and $paramssld["ht_view2_show_thumbs"] == 'on'){?>
                    <div><ul class="thumbs-list_<?php echo $portfolioID; ?>">
                        <?php   
                                global $wpdb;
                                foreach($imgurl as $key=>$img){ 
                                    $cimg_url = $img;                               
                                    $attachment = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE guid='".$cimg_url."'",'ARRAY_A');                               
                                    $attachment_title = get_the_title($attachment[0]['ID']);
                        ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $row->sl_url; ?>" class="group1" data-ttl="<?php echo $attachment_title; ?>" >
                                    <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>">
                                    </a></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                    </ul></div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if($paramssld["ht_view2_show_description"]=='on'){?><div class="description"><?php echo $row->description; ?></div><?php } ?>

                    <?php if($paramssld["ht_view2_thumbs_position"]=='after' and $paramssld["ht_view2_show_thumbs"] == 'on'){?>
                    <div><ul class="thumbs-list_<?php echo $portfolioID; ?>">
                        <?php   $imgurl=explode(";",$row->image_url);array_pop($imgurl);
                                foreach($imgurl as $key=>$img){?>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="group1"><img src="<?php echo $img; ?>"></a></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                    </ul></div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if($paramssld["ht_view2_show_popup_linkbutton"]=='on'){?>
                        <div class="button-block">
                        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"  <?php if ($row->link_target=="on"){echo 'target="_blank"';}?>><?php echo $paramssld["ht_view2_popup_linkbutton_text"]; ?></a>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php
    }?>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery('#huge_it_portfolio_popup_list_<?php echo $portfolioID; ?> .popup-wrapper_<?php echo $portfolioID; ?> .right-block ul.thumbs-list_<?php echo $portfolioID; ?> li a').click(function(){
        var width=jQuery(window).width();
        if(width<=767){
            jQuery('body').scrollTop(0);
        }
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var main_img_ttl =  jQuery(this).attr('data-ttl');      
        alert(main_img_ttl);
        jQuery(this).parents('.right-block').prev().find('.cls_img_ttl').html(main_img_ttl);
        jQuery(this).parents('.right-block').prev().find('img').attr('src',jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src'));
        return false;
    });
```

you can download file here : [LINK](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00894575077164282909)

Comment: Thank you Vrajesh,
$row->name is the project title which is already showing in the right side of the popup. I want to show the caption or title of each image which was added while uploading images through media library.

Comment: Not the file name, but there are 4 textboxes given while uploading image through portfolio plugin. which is title, caption, Alt text & Description. I want to show that particular title for each image. Hope you understood.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vrajesh, I need it for the big image only, not for the thumbnails. appreciate your help.

Comment: you can get it easily

Comment: hope you get your solution..i have updated my answer ..this is my last try :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time taken to help me. But this didn't solved the purpose as it is now showing the sector name for all big images.

Comment: so you want to put for perticular image?

Comment: For example there are three thumbnails in the popup. On clicking on each thumbnail it will show the bigger image. I want to show the bigger image along with the particular image title above the bigger image....

Comment: if you get your answer ..please up vote and right..thx..hope you appreciate my effort..

Comment: Sure, Let me try this.

Comment: Sorry vrajesh, It didn't helped. Now also it is only showing the sector heading like "Water Supply" for all images in the particular sector. If you can help I'll create a temp. development copy on my server and share with you personally. Anyway, Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Comment: Please provide your mail ID/Skype ID